# JMX short type parameter

Tags: java, jmx

Can you please advise how can I invoke method via JMX which accepts short parameter? I have method which returns String and accepts number of 'short' primitive type. When I try to invoke this method via JMX, it fails on exception:

```
try {
    String opSig[] = {"short"};
    Object opParams[] = {10};
    result = (String) mbeanServer.invoke(new ObjectName("-OMITTED-"), "getQueue", opParams, opSig);
```

...

Code fails on exception:

```
...
javax.management.MBeanException 
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing type of array for values to "Short"

```
try {
    String opSig[] = {"short"};
    Short opParams[] = {10};
    result = (String) mbeanServer.invoke(new ObjectName("-OMITTED-"), "getQueue", opParams, opSig);
```

OR alternatively:

```
try {
    String opSig[] = {"short"};
    Object opParams[] = {new Short("10")};
    result = (String) mbeanServer.invoke(new ObjectName("-OMITTED-"), "getQueue", opParams, opSig);
```